# Pan-Tilt Unit-D46-17 ROS Driver

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my ROS application I need to use the FLIR Pan_tilt Unit-D46-17 since it is the only one available  and I did not find any driver. I know this hardware is quite old. However, has someone implemented it already?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59133/pan-tilt-unit-d46-17-ros-driver/) by [Pedro Castro](https://answers.ros.org/users/4518/pedro-castro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess that is what you need:

http://wiki.ros.org/ptu46

It doesn't seem to publish /tf messages which is a bit sad. Is there anybody who has patch the driver?

---

Originally posted by [Francois](https://answers.ros.org/users/4341/francois/) with karma: 101 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-06**:
Since it is putting out joint_states, the usual way would be to have a URDF and use the robot_state_publisher to get TF